# Converting Collada to URDF

Tags: ros, urdf, dae, collada

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I know that there is a handy urdf-to-collada utility, collada_urdf; however, I am looking to go the other way around. Is there an existing utility to do this?

Best,

mjp

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/34214/converting-collada-to-urdf/) by [mjp](https://answers.ros.org/users/2280/mjp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2012-05-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) on 2012-05-17**:
Are you trying to just convert a single object, or multiple objects with joints, etc?

**Comment by [mjp](https://answers.ros.org/users/2280/mjp/) on 2012-05-17**:
It's a biped humanoid robot (HRP4C)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As far as I know, currently there are no collada->urdf convert software, however robot_model (ROS robot description library) support collada format, thus most of tools can use collada file as well as urdf file. See http://www.ros.org/wiki/collada_urdf/Tutorials/Exporting%20URDF%20to%20COLLADA

---

Originally posted by [Kei Okada](https://answers.ros.org/users/102/kei-okada/) with karma: 1186 on 2012-05-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mjp](https://answers.ros.org/users/2280/mjp/) on 2012-05-21**:
Thank you Kei for this information. We have some non-ROS software that can read URDF but not collada, and we were hoping there might be a way to export URDF once the collada format was read in.

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2012-05-21**:
Out of curiosity, what non-ROS software reads URDF? Also, are you able to post your COLLADA file?

**Comment by [mjp](https://answers.ros.org/users/2280/mjp/) on 2012-05-22**:
There is a Matlab based dynamics package we developed in-house at MIT and we recently made it use URDF by default. The collada file - I don't think I can post it because I had to agree to a license to get access to the WRL file. I could point you to the license page, though, if you are interested...